# how can i visualize price,year,state,product type and region in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have some dataset include

```
 $ data_inicials           : Date, format: "2004-05-09" "2004-05-09" ...
 $ region                  : chr  "CENTRO OESTE" "CENTRO OESTE" "CENTRO OESTE" 
 $ State                   : chr  "DISTRITO FEDERAL" "GOIAS" "MATO GROSSO" 
 $ Kind_of_Product         : chr  "ETANOL HIDRATADO" "ETANOL HIDRATADO" "ETANOL HIDRATADO" "ETANOL HIDRATADO" ...
 $ Mean_Market_Value       : num  1.29 1.16 1.39 1.26 1.18 ...
```

and i wanna visualize it. i write some code and combine;

-date, region, kind_of_product , mean_market_value- 
but ı have to filter region to get readable graph , here is my problem ;

how can I create a graph by use this variables ?

```
det %>% filter(Kind_of_Product != "GLP" ) %>%  
   ggplot(aes(x=data_inicials, y=Mean_Market_Value, color=Kind_of_Product, shape=State)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "Market Values", x = "Years", color = "Product")+
  ylim(c(.500,5.700)) + 
  ggtitle("Nordeste") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

I try to create like this ;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10CAiN_krOrxmBolEsSfjauE0_lxr77Ow/view?usp=sharing

edit :this is output belong the code below
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cYGL2h3ZpXd6XEJ6dCkCthLKmLiIaGsH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you wrote? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that's the image the code produces?

Comment: @MrFlick there is no problem that code. I wrote that just i show the graph and ask  how can i include region into that code ?

Comment: @RuiBarradas no , image was created with tableau and i want to make it in R.
I used data_inicials, Mean_Market_Value,Kind_of_Product, State but if ı don't add region in this code , I have to create 27 graph for all region

Comment: Maybe also use `facet_wrap(State ~ .)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas I couldn't explain myself enough , sorry for that but you give me the right solution. facet_wrap exactly what I looked for  . thank you for your help